# Output of custom directive is not received

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to receive events from a custom directive, but it is not working. I have several components in my application which successfully send events, so I made a minimal example:

```
<div *appDummyDirective="allTheThings" (dummyOutput)="dummyOuputDirective()">
    appDummyDirective
</div>
<appDummyComponent (dummyOutput)="dummyOuputComponent()"></appDummyComponent>
```

The callback for the component is called while the callback for the directive is not:

```
dummyOuputComponent() {
    console.log('dummyOuputComponent()'); //gets called
}

dummyOuputDirective() {
    console.log('dummyOuputDirective()'); //does not get called!
}
```

Here are the the definitions of the directive and the component.

```
@Directive({
selector: '[appDummyDirective]'
})

export class DummyDirective{
    @Output() dummyOutput = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input() appDummyDirective: any;

    constructor(private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private template: TemplateRef<any>) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
        setInterval(any => { this.dummyOutput.emit(null); console.log('fire dummy directive'); }, 1000);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'appDummyComponent',
    template: 'appDummyComponent'
})

export class DummyComponent{
    @Output() dummyOutput = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor() {
        setInterval(any => { this.dummyOutput.emit(null); console.log('fire dummy component'); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong with the directive?

Comment: Meaning you can't have @Output decorators on directives?

Comment: Are you sure you need a **structural** directive? Couldn't you use `appDummyDirective` instead of `*appDummyDirective`?

Comment: @stj242 If you can't use `@Output`.

Comment: @AngularFrance: Yes, it needs to be structural because my real world directive mimics ngFor.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Roman C: I'm sorry, but I don't quite get what you're saying. Is `@Output` supported on directives, yes or no?

Comment: @Simon Dufour: No error, the callback is simply ignored.

Comment: Did you check the Structural Directive Tutorial in the Advanced section of the Angular 2 site?
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it says nothing about `@Output`

Comment: Is the problem really the output though? Have you tried removing the setInterval or maybe.. putting the code in "@Input() set" instead of the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `@Output` does not work with syntactic sugar of `*`.

It works if you desugar the directive and apply the callback binding to the `template` element.

```
<template [appDummyDirective]="allTheThings" (dummyOutput)="dummyOuputDirective()">
    <div >
        appDummyDirective
    </div>
</template>
```